# Donde vem o termo “vanga”?

Tags: etimologia

Para a maior parte do pessoal, a ferramenta na figura abaixo é simplesmente uma ***pá***, tal como o era para mim antes de responder a [esta pergunta sobre o equivalente em português a *spade* e *shovel*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/are-spade-and-shovel-both-p%C3%A1). Mas na arte aquele tipo de pá é conhecido por (pá) ***vanga*** ou ***pá de corte***, como se pode ver no [site deste vendedor](http://fachi.com.br/produto-114557-p-de-corte-quadrada-c-cabo-71cm-tramontina), donde vem a figura abaixo.

[image]

A diferença é que as pás comuns são concebidas para levantar e transportar ou arremessar material, e por isso, além de serem mais largas, ou são abauladas ou têm bordas levantadas para segurar o material; a vanga, pelo contrario, é concebida para cavar, e por isso é mais estreita e direita, para penetrar e cortar o solo facilmente.

Os dicionários genéricos não trazem *vanga*; trazem [*pá direita* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/p%C3%A1) com o mesmo significado , mas este termo parece não ser usado. Encontrei *vanga* nalguns dicionários especializados, que contudo não explicam donde vem o termo:

> Vanga—cut shovel; ferramenta de sapa contruída de ferro, semelhante a uma pá, porém tem a forma laminar e cortante, sendo utilizada para cavar buracos e desbastar barrancos.
>   [(Mauri Adriano Panitz, *Dicionário Técnico Português – Inglês*, 2003.)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22vanga%20cut%20shovel%22&oq=%22vanga%20cut%20shovel%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7714j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>
> Vanga. Instrumento agrícola, de chapa metálica cortante e cabo longo de madeira, utilizado para fazer cortes verticais no coveamento, na abertura de canais etc.
>   [(Júlio S. I. Souza *et al.*, *Enciclopédia Agrícola Brasileira*, 1995.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wqU3SihZqfcC&pg=PT380&dq=vanga&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL4P6gj4PQAhXGNxQKHW5ADagQ6AEIxQEwFw#v=onepage&q=vanga&f=false)

*Pá de corte* compreende-se perfeitamente: este tipo de pá serve para cortar o solo. **Mas *vanga* donde vem e quando começou a ser utilizado?**

Comment: Por aqui nunca ouvi falar. Mas acho que a palavra vem do italiano. Procede?

Comment: @eightShirt Não faço ideia. Investiga isso e escreve-me uma resposta :)

Comment: @eightShirt Não sei se viste a pergunta sobre *shovel* e *spade* em português? Estes termos, *vanga* e *pá de corte* parecem ser termos relativamente técnicos que o grande público desconhece. Portanto não és nenhuma exceção.

Comment: Vi sim. Não encontrei muita coisa. Alguns sites dizem que é uma palavra que vem do latim. Vi que é mais usada no idioma italiano. No caso de *pá de corte*, pelo menos por aqui, não considero um termo técnico, embora *pá* seja um termo mais geral e mais utilizado.

Comment: em PT-BR eu nunca ouvi falar "vanga". Pá são ferramentas de vários tipos que se utilizam na construção civil. http://www.lojadomecanico.com.br/subcategorias/31/327/ferramentas-manuais-p-construcao-civil
Filtro com pá:
http://busca.lojadomecanico.com.br/?q=p%C3%A1

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar em "vanga" ou "pá de corte".  Contudo, nesse caso em particular, o fato de eu nunca ter ouvido não significa absolutamente nada.  Se eu fosse fazendeiro, agricultor ou fabricante/vendedor de utensílios agrícolas, e nunca tivesse ouvido falar, minha experiência teria algum significado.

Comment: @sola.carol As duas páginas que indicas têm vangas. Faz Ctr F "vanga", e encontrarás, ou simplesmente faz filtro com "vanga". Creio que são usadas sobretudo na agricultura; não tanto na construção.

Comment: @eightShirt E em italiano significa a mesma coisa? Se significa deve vir de lá.

Comment: @Jacinto realmente é possivel encontrar como Venga no mesmo site: http://www.lojadomecanico.com.br/produto/92126/31/327/vanga-quadrada-com-cabo-120cm-tramontina-77400524
Temos que conversar com alguem que trabalha na area de construçao civil :)

Comment: @sola.carol Eu acho que não é só o nome que é pouco conhecido; é o próprio instrumento também. Eu cresci numa família de agricultores, numa aldeia de agricutores, em Portugal, e não me lembro de alguma vez lá ver um pá daquelas.

Comment: @Jacinto se colocares vanga (italiano) no Google Tradutor ele traduz para pá ou espada em português.

Comment: @eightShirt Procede sim. Vê [Dizionario di Italiano](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/vanga.shtml) (já vem do séc. XIII); [Italian - English dictionary](https://www.google.pt/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=italian%20english%20translation&oq=italian%20en&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.14824j0j7) (em inglês não há dúvida que a coisa se chama *spade*); [Wikipedia Italiana](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanga).

Comment: @eightShirt Então, podes responder, não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vanga** vem do italiano, que significa cavar com uma pá no formato que descreve na pergunta (ou no formato de uma relha). Uma palavra em inglês que encaixa também neste tipo de pá é *ploughshare* porque remete a espada.

No Google Books (alguns livros contém a referência):

> Vanga is a word of Germanic origin which entered Late Latin in south-central Italy as a substitute for the Latin bipalium (Dizionario Etimologico Italiano, ed. C. Batisti and G. Alessio, Vol. V. Florence 1957, p. 3986)

Outra fonte que confirme o Latim Tardio e seu significado, no [DIZIONARIO ETIMOLOGICO ONLINE](http://www.etimo.it/?term=vanga&find=Cerca) mostra que é *campo*.

Em sueco campo é äng, em inglês é wong (palavra obsoleta), ambos podem ter relação com a palavra vanga.

Nunca ouvi falar em vanga, somente pá. O anuncio da pá é do Rio Grande do Sul, lá a imigração de europeus, assim como dos italianos, foi grande o suficiente para explicar o uso desta palavra pelo anunciante.

A Tramontina (empresa que fabrica o produto) é de imigrantes italianos e  Rio-grandense.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Creio que já não há dúvida que a origem é italiana. Um aspeto secundário: parece-me que *vangare* é que vem de *vanga* (o dicionário etimológico que linkas nem tem *vangare*). Tens ideia de quando é que a palavra começa a ser usada no Brasil? Sabes que na busca avançada do Google Books podes restringir a busca a língua portuguesa; se não, imagino que te apareçam sobretudo coisas em italiano.

Comment: Não tenho ideia, muitas palavras são usadas por conta da imigração (indiferente a época) mas desconheço o começo do uso delas.

Answer (score 0):

Pá, segundo o dicionário eletrônico Hauaiss da língua portuguesa 3.0 vem do latim:
[image]

Nessa mesma linha o Dicionário Etimológico on-line traz a seguinte definição:

**Origem da palavra pá**

do latim palla, pá, instrumento de ferro, com rebordos laterais, munido de um cabo, que serve para cavar terra. 

http://www.dicionarioetimologico.com.br/pa/.

Comment: Mas Lissandra, eu quero saber é a origem de ***vanga***, não de pá. Eu tenho um Houaiss em papel, mas não tem *vanga*.

Comment: Então, nos dicionários etimológicos que consultei em nenhum encontrei tal substantivo.

Comment: No entanto no dicionário digital Aulete < http://www.aulete.com.br/vanga> "Vanga" aparece com esta definição:
s. f. || (zool.) gênero de pássaros laniádeos de Madagáscar. || Também se dá por vezes este nome ao tamnófilo.

Que também não vai ao encontro do que o colega precisa. 
Quem sabe seja realmente um termo técnico utilizado apenas por quem trabalha no meio agrícola.

Comment: Creio que venha do latim "pala". Se fosse "palla" teria derivado em "pala".